# Focus not working in contenteditable div when generated dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, focus, contenteditable

I have very strange problem and struggling to fix it for the past one week. I generate a series of contenteditable div using PHP function ( essentially these are user posts and contenteitable divs are used to add another post). The functionality allows users to click on a more tag to get another set of contenteditble div.

The first time the functions works without any problem. I generate about 10 divs at a time and all 10 works just fine for the first time. When I click on the more tag, the next set of contenteditable div does not allow me to type. It loses focus. I tried div focus to set the focus back again but it does not seem to work.

The PHP function generating the divs is given below:

```
foreach($cursor as $record){
 foreach ($record as $key => $value){
      if($key=='Name'){
       $topText = "<font class='postHeaderLabel'>Posted By ".$value."</font>";
      }
      else if($key=='Category'){
       $topText =$topText."<font class='postHeaderLabel'> for Category ".$value."</font>";
      }
      else if($key=='Brand'){
       $topText = $topText."<font class='postHeaderLabel'> and brand ".$value."</font><br>";
      }
      else if($key=='Post'){
       $mainPost =$value;
       htmlentities($mainPost, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
       $mainPost = utf8_decode($mainPost);
       $mainPost = htmlentities($mainPost, ENT_QUOTES);
      }
      else if($key=='_id'){
       $id =$value;
      }
  }
  echo "<div class='postWrapper'>";
  echo "<div class='postHeaderDiv'>";
  echo $topText;
  echo "</div><div class='postTextDiv'>";
  echo $mainPost;
  echo "</div><div id='commentBoxInside' class='commentBoxInside".$id."' 
       tabindex='".$startindex."'  data-id='".$id."' contenteditable='true'>Enter Your
       Thoughts</div>";
  $startindex++;
  echo "<div id='textarealinksInside' class='textarealinksInside'>
        <a class='postInside' data-id='".$id."'>Post</a></div>";
  $innerQuery = array('$and'=>array(
        array('parentID'=>trim($id))
  ));
  $innerCursor = $collection_inner->find($innerQuery,array('Name'=>1,'Post'=>1))->limit(5)
                 ->skip(0)->sort($sort);
  $innerRecord = array();
  $innerTopText = "";
  $innerMainPost = "";
  foreach($innerCursor as $innerRecord){
        foreach ($innerRecord as $innerKey => $innerNextValue){
          if( $innerKey=='Name'){
            $innerTopText = $innerNextValue;
          }
          else if($innerKey=='Post'){
            $innerMainPost =$innerNextValue;
          }
        }
        echo "<div id='innerPostDiv' class ='innerPostDiv'>
              <font  class='innerpost'>".$innerMainPost."</font>
              <font class='innerlabel'> Posted by: ".$innerTopText."</font></div><br>";
  }
  echo "<div class='innermore' id='innermore-".$id.$innerpage."' 
           data-id='".$innerpage."' data-parentid='".$id."'>more...</div>";
  echo'<h2></h2>';
  echo "</div>"; 
}
echo "<div class='more' id='more-".$page."' data-id='".$page."'>
  <font class='morelabel'>more...</font></div>";
```

JQUERY FOR MORE

```
$('.more').live('click',function(){
var page = $(this).attr("data-id");
$.ajax({
        url: 'moreposts.php',
        data: {
            page: page
        },
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
        $("div#more-"+page).html(data);
        }
   });
});
```

Moreposts.php simply calls the function above

JQUERY FOR FOUCS (NOT WORKING)

```
$('#commentBoxInside').live('click',function(){
$(this).focus();
});
$('#commentBoxInside').live('focus',function() {
 var th = $(this);
    th.focus();
});
```

Comment: Hard to figure it out because of this unreadable server side script but IDs must be unique. Here you are rendering invalid HTML. BTW, would be really better to post rendered HTML as on client side instead of this ugly server side code

Comment: IDs are absolutely unique. As I mentioned first time around it works fine. problem starts happening when I generate next set of posts. Let me know if you want any further information

Comment: How can IDs be unique when you are echoing same element ID inside a loop. Please check your rendered HTML and see... For example, doesn't look like `#innerPostDiv` is unique. BTW, why not posting this rendred HTML client side?

Comment: Will you post rendered HTML or still not? What about a jsfiddle which replicates your issue?!

Comment: I will surely post it - let me work out a Jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's help. I finally got it resolved. Essentially the callback to DOM was happening in my JQuery which was overwriting the actions in the FOCUS or CLICK event of my div. A simple **return false** saved the day - as it instructs the DOM to avoid any further call back

Answer (score 0):

You cant bind functions to "id" in case of dynamically generated elements.Try this

```
$('.commentBoxInside').on('focus',function(){
   //Do you stuff here
});
```